# Using OAuth2RestTemplate in multi-thread context

Tags: multithreading, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

I'm using OAuth2RestTemplate in my Spring boot application and work with some resource through it as it encapsulates all the authentication info, so i can just send the requests, not worrying about tokens and other auth stuff.

That all works fine until i send the requests in parallel.

Because of the OAuth2RestTemplate has a `Session` scope (which is local as it contains user's session-related info), when i'm trying to use it in multi-thread environment, i get the following exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope
>   'session' is not active for the current thread; 
>       consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; 
>       nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, 
>       or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still
>   receive this message, 
>       your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

As I understand, this happens because these separate threads, where the code is being executed, are not wired with session.

The only solution i found for now is binding the session with new threads manually in code, but it i don't like it.

```
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

    Stream.of(1, 2, 3).parallel().forEach(it -> {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
        //do something
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    });

    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
```

There's a [ticket on Spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6479) where similar issue were discussed but still i still hope that there's some solution related to OAuth2RestTemplate.

So i'm wondering if anyone meet this and how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

For using session or request scope, you need to expose the RequestContextListener as a bean in your @Configuration class. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254079/configuring-requestcontextlistener-in-springboot) for example.

Comment: That doesn't work - at least for me - Even I tried to disable the already instantiated `RequestContextFilter` by spring and create my own with `threadContextInheritable` as `true` but it just doesn't work. Found this solution suggested here and it works like a charm: https://medium.com/@pranav_maniar/spring-accessing-request-scope-beans-outside-of-web-request-faad27b5ed57

Answer (score 0):

I was able to easily make use of `OAuth2RestTemplate` in multiple threads after I created my own bean, and made sure it was autowired correctly.

Before I was getting the exact same error message and it turned out that I didn't get the `OAuth2RestTemplate` I had created before:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails,
    SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {

    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory(clientFactory));

    return restTemplate;
}
```

In particular, the request factory wasn't present in the `RestTemplate` that got autowired, in fact it was `null`. Moreover, I actually had multiple different `OAuth2RestTemplate` beans, but `@Autowired` returned the exact same instance for all of them.

The key turned out to be in `OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details,
            oauth2ClientContext);
    return template;
}
```

Because of the `@Primary` annotation, all `@Autowired` instances apparently will get this one. Specifying the bean you want to get by parameter name, what usually worked before, didn't so in this case.

Adding a `@Qualifier` annotation resolved this issue:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myOwnOAuth2RestTemplate")
OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate;
```

Now, the correct instance is returned and when making a request, the auth server is called to get an OAuth2 token, as configured in the application configuration in `security.oauth2.client`.

However, I didn't attempt to autowire the `RestTemplate` from within a new thread. Instead, I pass it in as an argument. I'm not completely sure if this makes a difference, but since `getAccessToken()` is called by the `RestTemplate` during request execution, I assume it should also work when autowired into the new thread.

Comment: you've made the bean singleton so it would work fine because Spring can handle wiring singletons to different threads. But the issue here is that oAuth2RestTemplate has a session scope by default to store user's related auth info, so each user can use it's own bean. I'm not sure it this would work correctly with a Singleton oAuth2RestTemplate.

Comment: @ikryvorotenko Given that you want to use the OAuth2 access token of the authenticated principal in the `SecurityContext`, you actually don't need a separate bean for every user. You can update the `OAuth2ClientContext` with the token from the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContext`.

And I think the session-scoped beans are no "real" singletons due to Spring's proxy magic in the end.

In fact, we successfully use different `OAuth2RestTemplate` beans based on the approach described in my answer, as well as additional beans  that use static username/password credentials to get a token.