# Managing Facebook object within a Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

This is a more general Spring question that isn't necessarily a Spring Social Facebook issue; however, I'm asking the question here because it is not clear to me how Spring is managing the Facebook reference that is passed into the controller constructor.

I'm running this in a Spring boot app, version 1.5.3.RELEASE.

I've googled around and have read many things about how scoped-proxies work and whether the Controller is a singleton and such; but something is still not clear to me with this particular use case. My concern is over whether or not two or more simultaneous request will cause one reference to interfere with the other. It seems to me that there will be a conflict regardless of the scoped-proxy solution. To address this concern, I injected a Facebook and ConnectionRepository object into the controller constructor wrapped in a Provider class.

```
@Inject
public CopyGroupController(
        Provider<Facebook> facebook, 
        Provider<ConnectionRepository> connectionRepository) {
```

It appears to have injected meaningful data; but when attempting to run this code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ConnectionRepository repo = connectionRepository.get();
    this.userManager.createOrGetUser(
            repo.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class));

}
```

This failure occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

This creates more uncertainty because I thought the FacebookTemplate was being managed as a request or session scoped bean and that it would Inject as a Provider so the object would reside on ThreadLocale; so two or more concurrent requests will not conflict. Passing a request scoped bean in a controller singleton constructor doesn't make any sense to me either. So I'm puzzled as to why a user specific reference would even be passed into a constructor that should only be called once.

I've tried setting breakpoints in the constructor to verify whether or not there is a conflict; but The same error as above would occur. Could someone please explain to me whether or not this is an issue and if so; how is the best, most modern way to resolve it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a [RequestContextListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html)

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-request-scope-error-no-thread-bound-request-found/) you can find the problem detail

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30257691/1125284) you can get how to add in using spring boot